# Adding items from a list of lists (int items) to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a nested list into dictionary entries

a=[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 5]]

b={i[0]: i[-1] for i in a}

print(b) yields {1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5}

Could someone please tell me why I didn't get and how to get {1:4,1:5,2:3,2:4,2:5,3:5}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys. One way around is to store lists or sets inside the dictionary.
so what you can do is use dictionary mapping int to list

```
for i in a:
    if i[0] in dict:
        dict[i[0]].append(i[1])
    else:
        dict[i[0]]=[i[1]]
```

Comment: I am going to blame the fact that I'm tired that I forgot that a dictionary cant have duplicate keys

Comment: ya happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the first this is the process you need to follow

```
dictionary = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] in dictionary:
        dictionary[i[0]].append(i[-1])
    else:
        dictionary[i[0]] = [i[-1]]
```

This particular code will give the necessary output as {1 : [4 , 5], 2: [3, 4 ,5], 3: [5]} 
The reason that you did not get it for your code because dictionary can only have distinct keys, so that might be the error,

Hope this helps :)